# Partitioning a number into set of coprimes such that their product is maximum and sum of partition is the number itself

Tags: number-theory, coprime

Example 1)
Let the number be 7. Then we have a set {3,4}, so the product of the numbers is 10 and the numbers are mutually coprime.

Example 2)
for n=12, coprimes set = {3,4,5}, where product is 60 which is maximum.

Example 3)
n = 9, coprimes set = {4,5}, product is 20 which is maximum product.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: the problem is "how can we optimally partition a number into a set of coprimes such that their sum is number itself and product is maximum "

Comment: no it is not duplicate @RossMillikan

Comment: Why do you think it is not?  If the numbers are coprime the LCM and the product are the same.  Your value for $7$ is not correct because $3\cdot 4=12$

Comment: f(7) should return {3, 4}, f(12) should return {3,4,5} etc

Comment: @RossMillikan you're right f(7) -> {3,4},

Comment: Once you have the product you just factor it to get the set

Comment: do I need to check all the set and determine optimal(s), or are there any rules I can follow to get optimal set directly, for example in case of f(12) all possible cases are {2,10} , {3,9}, .. {2,3,7}, .. {3,4,5} .. etc, but the optimal answer is {3,4,5}.

Comment: All the elements have to be powers of primes, so there are not many to check

Answer (score 0):

The product is given by the Landau function, shown in [OEIS A000793](http://oeis.org/A000793) and beginning
$$ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 12, 15, 20, 30, 30, 60, 60, 84, 105, 140, 210,\\ 210, 420, 420, 420, 420, 840, 840, 1260, 1260, 1540, 2310$$
To get the set you can just factor these numbers.  The set always consists of powers of distinct primes.  The powers are chosen to be "roughly equal".  One of the higher values is $$120120=2^3\cdot 3 \cdot 5\cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$$
with sum $47$.  $48$ has the same partition with a $1$ added.  Then at $49$ we get 
$$180180=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$$
If there are $p$ factors the highest prime is about $p \log p$, so we can get a guess for the number of factors by solving $p^2 \log p =n$.  At n=$49$ this says we should have about $5.4$ factors, each about $9$.  We can guess we want $2^2, 2^3,$ or $2^4$ and $3^1$ or $3^2$ and first powers of the others and do a little search.